# Making polygon from two distinct polygons

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, geojson

I need to merge 2 distinct polygons into 1 polygon. My polygons are GeoJSONs.

Let's take for example these two polygons:

[image: example]

The result must be a polygon type and not a multi-polygon type.

My understanding is that if I merge\concatenate\union\dissolve them, I will get 1 entity (1 polygon) as I wanted, but with two different geometries, which inevitable will create a multipolygon.

In order for me to get what I want, I must somehow connect their geometries so it will be continuous and not discrete. So I'll have to do something that will result in this picture:

[image: desired_result]

I need the final area of this polygon to be minimized, so, creating, for example, a convex hull around these polygons is not a good solution.

Are there any ideas on how to implement it in Python or QGIS or anything else?

Comment: Is the solution therefore to find the two points of closest approach and add a near-zero width rectangle between those two points and then union those three polygons?

Comment: That might be an option, but I'm not sure how to do that in Python\QGIS. Do you happen to know?

Comment: I agree with @Spacedman, creating shortest line between polygons, buffer around that and finally a union of the three polygons should be possible to make automatic.

Comment: Are there only two polygons or do you have more?

Comment: Questions seeking ideas, rather than focusing on what you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck, can be fleshed out in the GIS Chat Room.

Comment: I might have more than 2 polygons but I can loop the solution. I see that my question is on hold.. I'll try to find a solution elsewhere, thank @Spacedman

Comment: If you want to write a new question asking "how to join two polygons by a line of their closest approach and to merge everything down to a simple polygon using R" then I can give you a solution.

Comment: Thanks, but we use Python in my office..